# Search in Char array

Tags: arrays, json, arduino, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

The Project I'm working on is a BURSTCOIN ticker, it gets its information from [Poloniex](https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker)
using an ESP8266 the first problem I had was that I was using http.getstring and it was to big to go into the string and it kept restarting the device. I then decided to use a buffer and now I can get the all the information to be printed to serial. Now the problem that I have is that I'm Looking for the information BTC_BURST in all of the chunks that I get. I'm wondering if instead of splitting my chunks by 128 or 256 bytes if i could split it after every } it receives.
Here is my code.

```
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <DNSServer.h>
#include <ESP8266WebServer.h>
#include <WiFiManager.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <Wire.h> 
//#include <ArduinoJson.h>
#define LCD_ROWS 2
#define LCD_COLS 16

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3F, LCD_COLS, LCD_ROWS);
WiFiManager wifiManager;
char apname[] = "ssid";
//char appass[] = "pass";



void configModeCallback (WiFiManager *myWiFiManager) {
  lcd.home();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Now Entering");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Setup Mode");
  delay(2000);
  lcd.home();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Pls Conn To AP");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(apname);
}


void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial.println();
  lcd.begin(4,5);
  lcd.backlight();
  startup();
  thankyou();
  lcd.home();
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Connecting");   
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("To Local WiFi");
  wifiManager.setTimeout(180);
  wifiManager.setAPCallback(configModeCallback);
  wifiManager.autoConnect(apname);//no password
  //wifiManager.autoConnect(apname,appass);//with password
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.print("Connected!");
  delay(2000); 
}

void resetesp(){
    wifiManager.resetSettings();
}

void startup(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();
  lcd.print("Ticker Test");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("By Draknoid");
  delay(2000);
}

void thankyou(){
  lcd.clear();
  lcd.home();
  lcd.print("Thank You!");
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print("Your Name Here");
  delay(2000);
}

void loop() {

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) { //Check WiFi connection status

    HTTPClient http;  //Declare an object of class HTTPClient
    http.begin("https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker","83:7D:87:4B:80:8B:B9:26:33:C0:5A:DC:30:18:58:D9:69:14:D1:4F");  //Specify request destination
    int httpCode = http.GET();//Send the request

    if(httpCode == HTTP_CODE_OK){

      int len = http.getSize();// get lenght of document (is -1 when Server sends no Content-Length header)
      // create buffer for read
      char jsonBuffer[128]; // verify this
      // get tcp stream
      WiFiClient * stream = http.getStreamPtr();

      // read all data from server
      while(http.connected() && (len > 0 || len == -1)) {
        // get available data size
        size_t size = stream->available();

        if(size) {
          // read up to 128 byte
          int c = stream->readBytes(jsonBuffer, ((size > sizeof(jsonBuffer)) ? sizeof(jsonBuffer) : size));
          // write it to Serial
          Serial.println(jsonBuffer);

          if(len > 0) {
            len -= c;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  delay(10000);
}
```

Comment: you can turn the little pieces into strings and search them with the methodical natives like `endsWith()`